# How to check several (n) last statuses of a systemd service?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I asked google and ChatGPT about that, i.e. see a specified `n` recent status of a service, obviously in chronological order.

ChatGPT told me this would work:

```
systemctl  status --quiet example.service -n 5
```

But this does NOT work, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

The manual page [`man systemctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) explains why that doesn't work for you:

> ### [`-n, --lines=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#-n)
>
> When used with `status`, controls the number of journal lines to show, counting from the most recent ones. Takes a positive integer argument, or 0 to disable journal output. Defaults to 10.

So `systemctl status example.service -n 5` shows LESS rather than more/all information.

> ### [`systemctl status`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#status%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6%7CPID%E2%80%A6%5D)
>
> ...
> Note that ***this operation only displays runtime status***, i.e.
> information about the ***current invocation*** of the unit (if it is
> running) ***or the most recent invocation*** (if it is not running anymore,
> and has not been released from memory).

But  in the same paragraph it does instruct you what to do instead to get information about  previous invocations:

> Information about earlier
> invocations, invocations from previous system boots, or prior
> invocations that have already been released from memory may be
> retrieved via **`journalctl --unit=`**.

Note that for many of my services I'll see a warning *"Journal has been rotated"*:

```
systemctl status httpd

● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-08-11 15:31:26 CEST; 6 days ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 21095 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 888 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─  888 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─30179 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. 
Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Where that last line is crucial and explains that the recommended action of running `journalctl --unit=` shows nothing particularly useful for me:

```
journalctl --unit=httpd.service

-- No entries --
```

Your mileage may vary for that.